# Rotating around a point relative to model position and rotation

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I have a model in space in Unity (C#), and this model is skydiving.  It's always facing the ground, but X and Z rotate.  The effect I'm going for is that when I rotate, rather than rotating around the model center, I rotate around a point a set distance directly to the models left or right, depending.  I already have the rotation logic, but what I don't have is how to determine the world position of "X pixels to the right" since rotation changes what is right/left.  For example:

When I start, left is -1,0; right is +1,0 x
I rotate around left 45 degrees.  left is still -1,0.  But now my position is (~) -.7,.7.  And since my "left" is still pointed at -1,0, "right is suddenly pointing at (~) 0,1.4

So how do I determine, given the model's Vector3 position, the model's X,Z rotation, and the offset, where "to the left" and "to the right" are.

For those visual types, Just Cause 2 did it right (though it can be difficult to tell sometimes):
http://youtu.be/C6H3PPfx1KI?t=2m

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to do the following:

1. Assign left / right coordinates in model space `left = (-1, 0, 0)`, `right = (1, 0, 0)`.
2. Transform rotation point(s) from model space to world space (e.g. `worldLeft = transform.TransformPoint(left)`).
3. Rotate around world space point (`transform.RotateAround(worldLeft, Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime)`).

Comment: It looks like that did exactly what I needed.  Thank you for the speedy response!  I can't be certain it's working because I think the camera system was set up terribly, but the numbers indicate that I'm rotating where I expect to.  I'll give this a nice big checkmark though.  Thanks again.