# Untiy Make an object rotate along axis its moving on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I want to make an object (let's say a cube), rotate at a steady rate on the same axis that's it's moving on. So if it changes direction from X to Z then the rotation would lerp from X axis into the Z axis and then continue rotating on Z axis.

How would I achieve this? Here's what I have at the moment, the cube just rotates on the z axis back and forth within a certain degrees.

```
public float Angle;
public float Period;

void Update()
{
    Animate();
}

void Animate()
{
    _time = _time + Time.deltaTime;
    float phase = Mathf.Sin(_time / Period);
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0f, 0f, phase * Angle));
}
```

Comment: `On the same axis it's moving on` would be difficult if the movement is not exactly on one of the axis. Consider the velicoty vector `v = (0,1,2)`. Where would resulting rotation go? You could try to e.g. normalize the velocity vector (that gives you the general direction in which the object is moving), then rotate using that vector (times a constant for controlling rotation speed).

Comment: generally, do NOT use Quaternions for any reason.  just use a trivial RotateAround call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotating around a point relative to model position and rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404372/rotating-around-a-point-relative-to-model-position-and-rotation)

Comment: @JoeBlow Ye, thanks. Just tested it and it's much easier.

Comment: GREAT .. see you on the next QA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
RotateAround
```

**Note** generally NEVER use Quaternion for any reason.

there are 1000s of questions on using RotateAround so just google.  In your case it sounds like you'll be changing (lerping, whatever) the axis of rotation itself.